# Getting a (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request

Tags: reactjs, html5-video

what i want to do is to access the camera laptop of the client and show it to the client the video that is being taken and then whenever the client is ready he can click a button and take his photo.

The part where I am getting stuck is - in showing the video in my React component. I get an error saying `'Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.'`

here's the code I have written

```
export default class UploadPhoto extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      url: '',
    };
    this.capturePhoto = this.capturePhoto.bind(this);
    this.playVideo = this.playVideo.bind(this);
  }

  playVideo() {
    // this.refs.vidRef.load();
    this.refs.vidRef.play();
  }

  capturePhoto() {
    const that = this;

        navigator.getUserMedia(
            // Options
          {
            video: true,
          },
            // Success Callback
            (stream) => {
                // Create an object URL for the video stream and
                // set it as src of our HTLM video element.
              const src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

              that.setState({
                url: src,
              });

              this.playVideo();
                // Play the video element to show the stream to the user.
            },
            // Error Callback
            (err) => {
                // Most common errors are PermissionDenied and DevicesNotFound.
              console.error(err);
            }
        );
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Upload Photo</h1>
            {this.capturePhoto()}
            <video
              ref="vidRef"
              src={this.state.url}
              type="video/mp4"
            />

          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Please tell me where am I going wrong and how to correct it.